# Mac Mini locked through Find My iPhone, can't unlock it

Tags: mac, unlock, find-my-iphone

So my friend locked his Mac with his iPhone using Find My iPhone.
Unfortunately there seems to be no way of unlocking it.

I have provided a picture of it below:
[image: Mac Mini locked screen]

I really hope someone here knows what to do. I appreciate all the help!

Comment: That looks like "can't find hard drive" -- though I may be missing something..

Comment: @JosephWeissman I agree it looks like that, but kind of strange considering we only remotely locked it with the iPhone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When your computer gets locked this way, you need to hold down the option key while booting in order to get access to your computer.  You will select the drive it is on and then enter a password to unlock it.

In the case where that doesn't allow you to fix the issue, you may have an issue with your hard drive. When the folder picture appears in the way it does it can mean that the computer can't find the OS to boot.

This can be because of a few things:

It can't find the drive with the OS to boot

- OS got corrupted
- Part of the drive where the OS is stored has failed
- The Hard Drive went bad or is failing
- Worst case: The logic board is failing

You should have him hold down the option key while booting and see if it finds his hard drive, if it does, have him select it and see if it boots.  If that fixes it, great.

I would still have him see a Genius so that they can check his drive to see if it is failing.  If he is under warranty and it is failing, they pop a new drive in for him for free as long as the computer isn't physically damaged.

This has happened to me, the option key thing while booting got me around it until I could get my drive replaced at the Apple Store.

I hope this answer helps you out.

Comment: I started looking for an answer using different Google terms and found the answer. We indeed had to hold the option key and enter the "Find My iPhone"-password. After that it booted happily. Thank you for your help. I'll accept this answer considering it gives a good overview of possibilities. If you can edit your answer and add in the solution that helped us so visitors can see that solution as well. Thank you.

Comment: @rickkuipers Thanks, glad I was able to help. I edited my answer to be more helpful for people who find this question.